# How widely supported are nested FeatureCollections in GeoJSON?

Tags: geojson

I know that FeatureCollections inside FeatureCollections are not supported according to the GeoJSON spec, but I have seen multiple implementations that do support it. Are nested feature collections widely supported, and how do implementations that don't support them handle them?

Are nested attributes widely supported?

Comment: There seems to be a 4 days old changeset in GDAL about flattening nested attributes. If you can read the code it may tell you something http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/28794.

Comment: I saw that change in GDAL, that was what prompted me to add on the question about nested attributes.